# Can Preload Imports Be Used Outside of Preload Script

Tags: electron

I am making an Electron timer app and want to know if it is possible for imports in the preload file to be used outside the file. For instance, if you use imports in `preload.js` but want to use those same imports in `renderer.js`, would it be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can expose those imports using the contextBridge.

For example,

```
const API = {
  triciConfig: config,
}

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('bridgeApi', API);
```

See https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/context-bridge/